# ArrayList or Aggregation with specified multiplicity

Tags: arraylist, staruml, multiplicity

I am just starting with UML (StarUML 5) so please excuse this really basic question.

Let's say a Person has multiple Characteristics, each of which has a Name and a Value. (This is just to keep things simple.) Suppose I create the `Characteristic` class accordingly.

I want to generate Java class `Person` with a property something like `ArrayList(Characteristic)`.

Should I add an attribute to the `Person` class like `ArrayList(Characteristic)`, or should I just use an Aggregation relationship between `Person` and `Characteristic` and specify the multiplicity as 0..* ?

On the first (ArrayList) approach I don't even model the multiplicity. On the second (Aggregation) approach the Java code creates a property in `Person` of type `Characteristic` but not a "List-like" property, i.e. it ignores the multiplicity in the diagram.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dave, this is a composition, a kind of UML association. Setting the composition as Ordered and not unique allows to generate the Java attribute as a List. It means you have a composition at the design level and a List at the implementation level. That's the code generator - or you if you don't use code generation - which correctly translates the UML diagram.

[Here's](http://repository.genmymodel.com/agencew2/ArrayListorAggregation) what I would design in your case and the Java code I generated (feel free to fork):

```
public class Person
{
    /**
     * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
     * <!--  end-user-doc  -->
     * @generated
     * @ordered
     */

    public List<Characteristic> characteristic;

    /**
     * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
     * <!--  end-user-doc  -->
     * @generated
     */
    public Person(){
        super();
    }    
}
```

Notice you can [import StarUML](http://www.genmymodel.com/staruml) projects in GenMyModel if you'd like to quickly design generate online.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a composition relationship to me.  In my opinion you're better off with the second approach using Aggregation/Composition.  [Here](http://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/) is an interesting read on one take on Attribute vs Association.  Regarding the failure of StarUML to implement the relationship correctly, you might be better off just implementing the `List` yourself.